# How do you test Firebase Dynamic Links in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

Based on the Firebase Unity documentation, you only need to add Firebase Dynamic Links SDK and then listen for incoming links like this in order to capture Dynamic links:

```c#
void Start() 
{
    DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
}

// Display the dynamic link received by the application.
void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
    Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}", dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
}
```

The dynamic link I have previously generated, correctly redirects me to the Google play store where my app exists. When I click on "open" from the play store, my app opens on the device but dynamic link information is not passed at all.

Do I need to create a new alpha version of my app to test this on Play Store?

Some people in Stackoverflow mentioned about Alpha version, but those people don't have an app released, whereas I do.

Also, is there way to test this in Unity editor?

I still need to write the code to parse it and it's kind of ridiculous to blindly code this.

Comment: Has the version of your app currently on the store [registered to receive](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/receive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still testing and don't want to release a version with Dynamic Links to production, you can release your build which has Dynamic Links to a beta release so you can be sure it's working as expected.

Otherwise, releasing to production also will work.

The build you are installing from play store needs to have the Dynamic Links library and also the codes anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the problem at the time of writing was with the Firebase SDK version. Firebase SDKs are not really reliable with Unity.